# Working with soap and xml in Extjs

Tags: extjs

I need to hit soap webservice, with soap xml request and headers, and get the response in xml in ExtJS.

Kindly share any easy working examples you have

Answer (score 0):

The [sencha docs on ajax request](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.Ajax) is probably your best starting point.
You can create an ajax request and set whatever headers you need.